# Count the total of preceding siblings and comments

Tags: xslt

I have many files that resemble the following a.xml file, although they are much larger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a version="3.0">
  <b bb="P1">
    <!--============== b:P1 c:1 ==============-->
    <c cc="1">
      <d dd="61">d1
      </d>
    </c>
    <!--============== b:P1 c:2 ==============-->
    <c cc="2">
      <d dd="17">d2
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

For each c there is only one preceding comment.

I want to output a file with the same structure of the following a.csv file:

```
1|1|a|0| |0| |0|
2|1|a|1|b|0| |0|
3|1|a|1|b|1|!|0|
3|1|a|1|b|2|c|0|
4|1|a|1|b|2|c|1|d
3|1|a|1|b|3|!|0|
3|1|a|1|b|4|c|0|
4|1|a|1|b|4|c|1|d
```

It represents the hierarchical tree for a.xml:

1. Field 1 is the hierarchical level. For instance a has level 1, b has level 2, etc.
2. Fields 2, 4, 6 and 8 are equal to:

   - if the current node's level is less than the current field's level then 0
   - else the total number of preceding siblings and comments plus one
3. Field 3, 5, 7 and 9 are equal to:

   - if the current node's level is less than the current field's level then " "
   - else either "!" if the current node is preceded by a comment or the node's name

In this example level 3 contains comments.

I cannot find a good way to do a for-each that includes both nodes and comments. When I use `<xsl:for-each select="*">` I only loop through the nodes.

Because of that, I've come out with the following xslt, that checks if the current node is preceded by a comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
   <xsl:variable name="elm01" select="local-name()" />
   <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
   <xsl:text>|0| |0| |0|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:variable name="elm02" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
    <xsl:text>|0| |0|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
     <xsl:variable name="elm03" select="local-name()" />
     <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::comment()[1]">
      <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|!</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|0|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
     <!-- TODO: I want to count the total of preceding siblings and comments -->
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*|comment())+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm03" />
     <xsl:text>|0|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:variable name="elm04" select="local-name()" />
      <xsl:text>4</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm03" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm04" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However when I run the following command:

```
xsltproc a.xslt a.xml > a.csv
```

I get the following a.csv file:

```
1|1|a|0| |0| |0|
2|1|a|1|b|0| |0|
3|1|a|1|b|1|!|0|
3|1|a|1|b|1|c|0|
4|1|a|1|b|1|c|1|d
3|1|a|1|b|2|!|0|
3|1|a|1|b|2|c|0|
4|1|a|1|b|2|c|1|d
```

Please notice that field 6 is incorrect:

- it is equal to 1 both for the 1st comment and the 1st node c and its children
- it is equal to 2 both for the 2nd comment and the 2nd node c and its children

Do you have any solutions to suggest?

SOLUTION (by Tim)

I can now get the correct output by using the following xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
   <xsl:variable name="elm01" select="local-name()" />
   <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
   <xsl:text>|0| |0| |0|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:variable name="elm02" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
    <xsl:text>|0| |0|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
     <xsl:variable name="elm03" select="local-name()" />
     <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::comment()[1]">
      <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::comment())"/>
      <xsl:text>|!</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|0|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::comment())+1"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm03" />
     <xsl:text>|0|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:variable name="elm04" select="local-name()" />
      <xsl:text>4</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm01" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm02" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*|../preceding-sibling::comment())+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm03" />
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text><xsl:copy-of select="$elm04" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively you can also use the xslt in Tim's reply, that gets rid of repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::comment()) + 1" />
```

Or this would work too...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::node()[self::*|self::comment()]) + 1" />
```

But you can also use `xsl:number`

```
<xsl:number count="*|comment()" />
```

Your stylesheet does seem a bit over-complicated though, with much repetition. Try this more generic one instead. This recursively calls each level, passing in the constructed line each call to save having to build it each time.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:param name="maxLevel" select="4" />

  <xsl:template match="*|comment()">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="prev" />
    <xsl:variable name="new">
        <xsl:value-of select="$prev" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="*|comment()" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>!</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$level" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$new" />
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="levels" select="$maxLevel - $level" />
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="prev" select="$new" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>        
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="pad">
      <xsl:param name="levels" />
      <xsl:if test="$levels > 0">
          <xsl:text>|0| </xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="pad">
              <xsl:with-param name="levels" select="$levels - 1" />
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiy

Comment: Thank you Tim. I have tested successfully the 1st and 2nd suggestions. I'm not quite able to make it work with the 3rd suggestion, but it does not matter. I have also tested successfully your xslt, which seems much smarter than mine. I'm going to update my post with the solution applying your 1st suggestion.